# Python Optional Parameters Censoring

Tags: python, class, sequence

I am trying to make an `__init__()` function for a class. Here is an example of where I get stuck.

```
class Names():
    """a class for storing a number of names"""

    def __init__(self, names): #names can be any sequence of strings
        """takes a sequence of names and puts them into a list"""
        self.name_list = []
        for element in names:
            self.name_list.append(element)
```

But when I try:

```
Names("John", "Bobby", "Sarah")
```

I get the error message

> TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Is there a way to make this work for any arbitrary number of names or in other words a sequence of names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You need to use the `*` operator to signal a variable number of arguments. Like so:

```
class Names():
    """a class for storing a number of names"""

    def __init__(self, *names): #names is can be any sequence of strings
        """takes a sequence of names and puts them into a list"""
        self.name_list = list(names)
```

Then however many names you give will be stored in `name_list`.

```
>>> Names("John", "Bobby", "Sarah")
<__main__.Names instance at 0x102b1c0e0>
```

You can prettify this a bit by giving the class its own `__repr__` method. E.g.:

```
def __repr__(self):
    clsname = self.__class__.__name__
    namestr = ", ".join(repr(n) for n in self.name_list)
    return "{0}({1})".format(clsname, namestr)
```

Then:

```
>>> Names("John", "Bobby", "Sarah")
Names('John', 'Bobby', 'Sarah')
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Good point! `names` will natively be a tuple. That's suitable / sufficiently "list-like" for many sequence operations, but some will need a true `list`. Cast added.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing names as arguments pass a list of names then u don't need to make any changes to your `__init__()` method

so instead of

```
Names("John", "Bobby", "Sarah")
```

use

```
Names(["John", "Bobby", "Sarah"])
```

and your  init() code will work fine.